# Doubt regarding a question DS160 application (countries you have visited)

Tags: usa, f1-visas, student-visas

While filling DS160 I bumped into this question which was asking about the  countries I visited. Should I mention transit too? Because I had a transit in Germany (when travelling from Sweden to India) and in Denmark (while travelling from India to Sweden) in the years 2020 and 2019 respectively. I have the stamps in my passport too. Do I have to mention in the form under the question of visited countries? I’m really confused? I tried finding the answer but I couldn't find any relevant to transit. Could someone please guide me with this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the stamp on your passport, include it as a visited country. If they ask the reason, just mention you were in a connection

Comment: Good answer.  I would go farther and mention transit countries even if there was no stamp (for example, Germany in transit from the UK to India).  In general, if you're unsure about whether to mention something, mention it and let the authorities decide whether it's significant.  They're far more likely to react unfavorably if you fail to mention something they want to know about than if you do mention something they don't care about.  On my US customs declarations I write _(transit),_ but I don't know whether this is possible with the DS-160.